# Apexcharts, join up series lines

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, apexcharts

I have an issue when trying to join 2 series lines in apexcharts.

```
{
name: 'trend-1'
trend: [
      {
        time: '2024-02-15 00:00',
        value: '99.6',
      },
      { time: '2024-02-15 01:00', value: '98.7' },
      {
        time: '2024-02-15 02:00',
        value: '98.1',
      },
      { time: '2024-02-15 03:00', value: '97.2' },
      {
        time: '2024-02-15 04:00',
        value: '97.0',
      },
      { time: '2024-02-15 05:00', value: '98.2' },
      { time: '2024-02-15 06:00', value: '98.5' },
    ],
target: '98.0'
}
```

I can process this data into a green and red series lines with the code below

```
const greenSeries = {
  name: 'KPI -1',
  data: data.trend.map(item => ({
    x: item.time,
    y: parseFloat(item.value) >= parseFloat(data.target) ? item.value : null
  }))
};

const redSeries = {
  name: 'KPI -1',
  data: data.trend.map(item => ({
    x: item.time,
    y: parseFloat(item.value) < parseFloat(data.target) ? item.value : null
  }))
};
```

Which gives this output

```
greenSeries =
    { 
        name: 'KPI -1',
        data: [
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 00:00',
                y: '99.6',
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 01:00'
                y: '98.7',
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 02:00'
                y: '98.1',
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 03:00'
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 04:00'
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 05:00'
                y: '98.2',
            },
            {
                x: '2025-02-15 06:00'
                y: '98.1',
            }
        ]
    }


redSeries =
    { 
        name: 'KPI -1',
        data: [
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 00:00',
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 01:00'
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 02:00'
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 03:00'
                y: '97.2',
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 04:00'
                y: '97.0',
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 05:00'
                y: null,
            },
            {
                x: '2024-02-15 06:00'
                y: null,
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the chart looks like this...

[image]

The issue I've been really struggling to get is to join the lines up...

From the data at the very top, target is 98.0, so green if above and red if below the target.

How can I join up the lines from green to red and red to green please??

While also including handling for say, its below target at the start, there may be more than one instance of dropping below the target etc....